# Internet browsers having certificate trouble after BIOS update

Tags: windows, google-chrome, bios

After trying to flash an updated bios for my new 6 core processor, I had to revert to the previous bios due to startup issues. Since then, mozilla firefox closes after a few seconds of being open, and many sites on chrome have unvalidated certificates. I can't figure out what happened or how to fix it. I had to pull the CMOS battery out in order to reset to my original bios, as I didn't install a revert program beforehand.

Comment: It is unlikely the certificate issue is related to your bios, but please provide details about your hardware and specific OS to be certain.

Answer (score 4):

The only reason I can think of why the BIOS update and/or CMOS settings reset could affect validity of the certificates is system time reset - If currently your system time is way in the past (or future for that mater) - all certificates would become expired or not yet valid because they have a specific term they were issued for.